# Implement Google 3D maps for my Android app?

Tags: android, twitter, 3d, maps

is it possible to use the new Google 3D Maps for Android in my app? I'm developing an app and I want to add this.

thanx!

http://www.google.com/mobile/maps/3d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have created this one: [Nutiteq 3D Maps SDK](http://nutiteq.github.com/hellomap3d/). This is a SDK, not application, so you can use it in your apps as replacement of Google Maps SDK.

[image: Nutiteq SDK 2.0 sample]

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The Google Maps application no longer uses the same SDK `MapView` that we third-party developers use. Someday, perhaps they will update it, and then 3D maps will be possible, but not as of today.

Sorry!

---

**UPDATE**

[Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) allows 3D views, via camera tilt, if you are in a location that supports them:

[image]