# Perspective google map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I need to get a map with a simple perspective view in android. Just like a regular map, but few degrees rotated, as we can have in Google Map App by dragging map with two fingers. As I understand, there is no possibilities to do it in the API. Is it possible?

Comment: I found the answer here. http://www.droidforums.net/forum/samsung-droid-charge/167045-navigation-problems-only-top-down-view.html You have to click the red/white compass arrow to switch between 3D and 2D overhead view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771201/implement-google-3d-maps-for-my-android-app) will help: (Although it may be disappointing),

Basically, it says that you can't. Just searching around, I couldn't find any APIs or tutorials on how to do this, but that question from some time back *claims* that it's not yet possible.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's available now with the new Google Maps Android API.  Granted, it's an entirely new API that requires a new API key and tweaking on how you display markers.  You get the perspective camera for free as well as a few other cool things.  Check it out.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/